# Pass variable to anon function / callback

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous-function

I am trying to pass `product` into the `find()` function that contains a `.toArray()` anonymous function containing both `error` and `array`. Unfortunately this entire `find()` function runs within an iteration and only the first value goes in. How do I pass `product` to the `callbacks`?

```
var find = function(product,callbacks){
    foos.find({
        "foo": product.bars,
    }).toArray(function (error, array) {
        if(error){
            callbacks.error(product,error);
        } else if (array.length == 0) {
            callbacks.none(product);
        } else {
            callbacks.exists(product);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand the question. Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: Could you show us those `find` and `toArray` functions, do you use a common library?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing, since it depends on the specification of `foos.find` (it doesn't look like jQuery's `find` method) and what its return value's `toArray` method does.

Comment: It's all https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this function i was processing `products` with `forEach()` then had this run in a callback within that. This was big trouble. Processed `products` with a regular `for` and now it works.

#### Old code

```
var products = function(data,callback){
    products.forEach(function(product){
        insert.product_id = product.id;
        var variants = product.variants;
        variants.forEach(function(variant){
            insert.sku = variant.sku;
            insert.variant_id = variant.id;
            return callback(insert);
        });
    });
}
```

#### New code

```
var products = function(data){
    var insert = [];
    var products = data.products;
    for(var pKey in products){
        var product = products[pKey];
        var variants = product.variants;
        var set = {}
        set.product_id = product.id;
        for(var vKey in variants){
            var variant = variants[vKey];
            set.sku = variant.sku;
            set.variant_id = variant.id;
            insert.push(set);
        }
    }
    return insert;
}
```